# regex, avoid extra zero-length matching

Tags: java, regex

Say that I have the following regex; (i'm using java.util.regex package. java version 1.7.0_21)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\G[^,]*(,|$)");
```

calling repeatedly find(), i should be able to extract the fields in a CSV like the following:

```
String myCSV = "a,b";
```

So let's try it with the simplest possible loop. Just echo infos on each matching.

```
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myCSV);

    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println("Match found from: " + m.start() 
                           + " (included) to: " + m.end()+ " (excluded),"
                           + " matching:  '" + m.group() + "'. Does it hit end?" + m.hitEnd());

    }
```

While i tried to construct my regex so that it wouldn't allow for zero-length matchings, quite surprisingly, it does:

```
Match found from: 0 (included) to: 2 (excluded), matching:  'a,'. Does it hit end?false
Match found from: 2 (included) to: 3 (excluded), matching:  'b'. Does it hit end?true
Match found from: 3 (included) to: 3 (excluded), matching:  ''. Does it hit end?true
```

Look at the 3rd matching, that in my idea should not be present. Indeed my regex required that each matching ends with either (,|$). So, the second matching, is required to reach and "consume" the end of the string, to be valid: it doesn't leave it for a further match! 
And This seems confirmed by the hitEnd being true, just after the second match!.
 **But** this seems not be considered by the find internal state, that searches for a further matching, and at this point it obviously find it, because the regex allows for a zero lenght matching when followed by the end of the string *because it is a valid matching*, since each field is allowed to be an empty string (if this wasn't the case, using + instead of * would obviously solve the problem).
I'm asking two things.
1) a fix for this problem 
2) the reason why it seems to match the end of the string two times

Comment: Untested: try `"\\G((?=.)[^,])*,?"` (remind me again, what is `\\G` for?).

Comment: [Per this part of Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), try "`+?`" for `Reluctant` matching.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question has several possible answers. One is to use lookbehind to ensure that you're always starting a match after the beginning of the line or a comma, as in:

```
(?<=^|,)([^,]*)(?:,|$)
```

as shown in http://rubular.com/r/L5d8lZ44kh

For demo purposes, I introduced a capture group for the non-separator match and used a non-capturing group for the separator match. Neither of these changes are necessary in your situation; you only need to be sure to include the lookbehind change.

Also, as @sin pointed out in the comment, there is no need to match the end of the previous match, so I eliminated the \G. This would not be true if you ever restricted the acceptable CSV "value" characters to a narrower set than everything but the comma.

The answer to the second question is a little trickier. To begin with, it's important to understand that the anchor positions (e.g. beginning of line, end of last match, end of line, etc.) are never *captured* by a regex; they are only matched against. The match position remains unchanged. So multiple successive expressions can match the same anchor point, as you experienced.

This works ok except that there needs to be a way to avoid matching an infinite number of zero-length expressions. There are at least a couple of ways to achieve this, as discussed in http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html. Although it's not really critical to your questions, I tried through Googling to figure out which approach the Java implementation uses, but couldn't.

Comment: Java is one of the "most flavors" the author alluded to: successive calls to `find()` will never return two matches that start at the same position.

Comment: Through trial and error, I came up with this `((?:^|(?<=,))[^,]*$|[^,]*,)` then combined them into basically what you have. I don't see a need for the `\G` anchor here, do you? Also, does Java allow lookbehinds with alternations?

Comment: I had what you had initially, but then I thought it would accept non-standard CSV formats in the absence of any requirement that the next match started at the end of the previous one (i.e. it would allow "junk" between two separator characters). But now that I think about it a little more, you're right that it's not doing anything, as all text is either the one separator (i.e. the `,`) or it's an acceptable CSV value. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the reason, perhaps it looks for a match from each possible starting point (i.e. from the `b` and also from the end of the string)?

To fix it though, you can add another part at the start of the regex that looks for either the start of the string or a comma.

So something like: `"(,|^)[^,]*(,|$)"`

---

But you would need to chop off the extra commas from the match, perhaps capturing a group rather than the entire match?

E.g. `"(,|^)([^,]*)(,|$)"` and then get it with `m.group(2)`

Comment: I think you're on the right track with matching the leading comma, but you also have to drop the part that matches the *trailing* comma.

Comment: @Alan I see what you mean, I'd missed the meaning of the `\G` - though I think a better way would be to still match both commas but drop the `\G`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that easy solution is to split your regex in two parts

1. one that can accept empty Strings as long as there is `,` after it.
2. other that will not accept empty `non-comma` strings if it placed at the end

This seems to do the trick

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\G[^,]*,|\\G[^,]+$");

String myCSV = "a,,b";
Matcher m = p.matcher(myCSV);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match found from: " + m.start()
            + " (included) to: " + m.end() + " (excluded),"
            + " matching:  '" + m.group() + "'. Does it hit end?"
            + m.hitEnd());
}
```

Output:

```
Match found from: 0 (included) to: 2 (excluded), matching:  'a,'. Does it hit end?false
Match found from: 2 (included) to: 3 (excluded), matching:  ','. Does it hit end?false
Match found from: 3 (included) to: 4 (excluded), matching:  'b'. Does it hit end?true
```

---

Other and even simpler way would be just using `split` on every comma. In case you would want to also have last empty string you can use split with negative limit like

```
for(String token:"a,,b,".split(",",-1)){
    System.out.println("'"+token+"'");
}
```

Also if you want to include commas into tokens you can use look-behind mechanism to split after each comma

```
for(String token:"a,,b,".split("(?<=,)",-1)){
    System.out.println("'"+token+"'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,]+(?=\\s*|\\s*$)");
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/VLGORy)**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a regex solution -

```
 #  "(?:^|(?<=,))([^,]*)(?:,|$)"

 (?:
      ^ 
   |  (?<= , )
 )
 ( [^,]* )                          # (1)
 (?: , | $ )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `,` after the value to appear as part of the match, you can just match to `(^|,)` at the start rather than `(,|$)` at the end, which would eliminate your problem:

`\G(^|,)[^,]*`

[RegexHero shows 2 matches](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=70ea7fad-7649-473b-8b2d-c088a8d3b0b8) instead of [3 matches](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=a4254dcc-121b-421f-a04a-f28b770f7ef6)

If you're working with multiple rows in the same string then add your row delimiter to the negated class.